# How to add space to a particular row or column in a matrix diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to make a diagram using matrix environment in TikZ:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes=block,
        nodes={align=left, text width=2.75cm}, % New!
        column sep=3em,
        row sep=2em},
    block/.style={draw=blue!80, thick, fill=blue!20, 
        rounded corners,
        minimum width=8em,
        minimum height=4em,
        align=center, },
    vhilit/.style={draw=black, thick, %dotted,
        inner sep=1em,
        },
    ]


\matrix[mymatrix, nodes={anchor=center, align=center}] (mx)  { % at (11,10) 
    \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a11) {}; & \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a12) {}; & \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a13) {}; & \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a14) {}; & \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a15) {};  \\
    \node[block] (a21) {Listening\\Channel}; & {Reading and\\Transmitting} & {Content\\ Management} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a24) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a25) {};  \\
    {Backoff} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a32) {}; & {Collision\\Management} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a34) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a35) {};  \\
    \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a41) {}; & {FSA Frame\\Inicialization} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a43) {}; & {Tags State\\Control} & {FSA Frame\\Inicialization}  \\
     \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a51) {}; & {Slot Inventory\\Time Accounting} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a53) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a54) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a55) {};  \\
     \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a61) {}; & {Compute Reader\\Tx/Rx Gain} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a63) {}; & {Compute Tag's\\Tx/Rx Gain} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a65) {};  \\
     \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a71) {}; & {Compute\\Backscattered Power} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a73) {}; & {Compute Tag's\\Received Power} & {Tag\\Activation}  \\
     \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a81) {}; & {Compute\\Interferences} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a83) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a84) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a85) {};  \\
     \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a91) {}; & {Compute\\SINR/BER} &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a93) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a94) {}; &  \node[draw=none, fill=none] (a95) {};  \\
  };


\draw[thick] (a21) -- (mx-3-1);
\draw[thick] (a21) -- (mx-2-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-2-2) -- (mx-4-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-2-2) -- (mx-2-3) node [midway, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (mid) {}; 
\draw[thick] (mid) |- (mx-3-3);
\draw[thick] (mx-4-2) -- (mx-5-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-5-2) -- (mx-6-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-6-2) -- (mx-6-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-6-4) -- (mx-7-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-7-2) -- (mx-7-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-4-4) -- (mx-4-5);
\draw[thick] (mx-4-5) -- (mx-7-5);
\draw[thick] (mx-7-5) -- (mx-7-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-7-2) -- (mx-8-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-8-2) -- (mx-9-2);
% \node [coordinate, at (mx-5-2)] (test1) {};
% \draw[thick] (mx-5-2) -- ({$(mx-5-2)!.5!(a51)$}) |- (mx-9-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-5-2) to [bend right=90] (mx-9-2);
\draw[thick] (a21) to [out=180,in=180] (mx-8-2);


\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[vhilit, fit=(a11) (a12) (a13) (a14) (a15), align=center, fill=brown!45, opacity=0.7, text opacity=1, text=black] {{Task Assignment\\Initialization/Close Tasks}};
    \node[vhilit, fit=(a21) (mx-2-2) (mx-2-3) (a24) (a25) (mx-3-1) (a32) (mx-3-3) (a34) (a35) ,fill=red!25, opacity=0.7, align=left, text opacity=1] {};
    \node[vhilit, fit=(a41) (mx-4-2) (a43) (mx-4-4) (mx-4-5)  (a51) (mx-5-2) (a53) (a54) (a55) , fill=green!25, opacity=0.6, align=left, text opacity=1] {\large{FSA}};]
    %
    \node[vhilit, fit=(a61) (mx-6-2) (a63) (mx-6-4) (a65)  (a71) (mx-7-2) (a73) (mx-7-4) (mx-7-5)  (a81) (mx-8-2) (a83) (a84) (a85)  (a91) (mx-9-2) (a93) (a94) (a95) , fill=pink!30, opacity=0.7, align=left, text opacity=1] {\large{PHY}};

\end{scope}

\draw[blue, thick]({$(mx-2-3)!.5!(a24)$} |- mx-2-3.north) -- ({$(mx-2-3)!.5!(a24)$} |- mx.south);


  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

that produces:

[image]

I would like to add more space to the first column width to write 'LBT', 'FSA' and 'PHY', and
make room to write the words 'Reader' and 'Tag' at both sides of the vertical line like in
the following drawing:

[image]

Besides, I do not know how to make the links between 'listening channel' block and 'Compute interferences' cornered and not bent like in the above handmade drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is too messy... so I reformat them and make some change.

The main idea is to use

```
  a/.style={
    append after command={
      (#1,0) coordinate (left-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
    }
  },
```

to expand the cell border.

The effect of `block/.default` is whenever no value is provided for `block`, then the default value is used instead.

Column width is the width of the widest cell of the column, so only one call of `a=-2` or `block=-2` will expand the column.

But the goal is to expand the fitting area. Original fitting area is the rectangle decided by the upper left node and lower right node. Now we want to extend the left border. The easist way is to put an empty node/coordinate on the left of **upper left node**, some node of the fitting area is an empty node, so I use `a=-2` to extend the border, otherwise `block=-2` is enough (the combination of original block style and `a=-2`), which is more convenient than `block, a=-2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, fit, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  a/.style={
    append after command={
      (#1,0) coordinate (left-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
    }
  },
  block/.style={
    draw=blue!80, thick, fill=blue!20,
    rounded corners,
    align=center,
    anchor=center,
    a=#1,
  },
  block/.default=0,
  mymatrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={
      minimum width=8em,
      minimum height=4em,
      text width=2.75cm,
    },
    column sep=3em,
    row sep=2em
  },
  vhilit/.style={
    draw=black, thick, %dotted,
    inner sep=1em,
    rounded corners,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [mymatrix] (mx) {
%% row 1
  |[a=-4]|
  &&&&\\
%% row 2
  |[block=-4]|{Listening\\Channel}
  & |[block]|{Reading and\\Transmitting}
  & |[block=5]|{Content\\ Management}
  &&\\
%% row 3
  |[block]|{Backoff}
  && |[block]|{Collision\\Management}
  &&\\
%% row 4
  |[a=-4]|
  & |[block]|{FSA Frame\\Inicialization}
  && |[block]|{Tags State\\Control}
  & |[block]|{FSA Frame\\Inicialization}
  \\
%% row 5
  & |[block]|{Slot Inventory\\Time Accounting}
  &&&\\
%% row 6
  |[a=-4]|
  & |[block]|{Compute Reader\\Tx/Rx Gain}
  && |[block]|{Compute Tag's\\Tx/Rx Gain}
  &\\
%% row 7
  & |[block]|{Compute\\Backscattered Power}
  && |[block]|{Compute Tag's\\Received Power}
  & |[block]|{Tag\\Activation}
  \\
%% row 8
  & |[block]|{Compute\\Interferences}
  &&&\\
%% row 9
  & |[block]|{Compute\\SINR/BER}
  &&&\\
};

\draw[thick] (mx-2-1) -- (mx-3-1);
\draw[thick] (mx-2-1) -- (mx-2-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-2-2) -- (mx-4-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-2-2) -- coordinate [midway] (mid) (mx-2-3);
\draw[thick] (mid) |- (mx-3-3);
\draw[thick] (mx-4-2) -- (mx-5-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-5-2) -- (mx-6-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-6-2) -- (mx-6-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-6-4) -- (mx-7-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-7-2) -- (mx-7-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-4-4) -- (mx-4-5);
\draw[thick] (mx-4-5) -- (mx-7-5);
\draw[thick] (mx-7-5) -- (mx-7-4);
\draw[thick] (mx-7-2) -- (mx-8-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-8-2) -- (mx-9-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-2-1.west) -- ++(-1, 0) |- (mx-8-2);
\draw[thick] (mx-5-2.west) -- ++(-1, 0) |- (mx-9-2);
\tikzset{
  myfont/.style={pos=.01, text=red, font=\bfseries\sffamily\large}
}
\draw[blue, thick]
  ({$(mx-2-3)!.5!(mx-2-4)$} |- mx-2-3.north) --
  node[left, myfont] {READER}
  node[right, myfont] {TAG}
  ({$(mx-2-3)!.5!(mx-2-4)$} |- mx.south);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \node[vhilit, fit=(left-1-1)(mx-1-1)(mx-1-5), align=center, fill=brown!45, opacity=0.7, text opacity=1, text=black] {{Task Assignment\\Initialization/Close Tasks}};
  \node[vhilit, fit=(left-2-1)(mx-2-1)(mx-3-5) ,fill=red!25, opacity=0.7, align=left, text opacity=1] {\large{LBT}};
  \node[vhilit, fit=(left-4-1)(mx-4-1)(mx-5-5) , fill=green!25, opacity=0.6, align=left, text opacity=1] {\large{FSA}};]
  \node[vhilit, fit=(left-6-1)(mx-6-1)(mx-9-5) , fill=pink!30, opacity=0.7, align=left, text opacity=1] {\large{PHY}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: connecting arcs presently drawn need to be sharp corners as required by the OP --`Besides, I do not know how to make the links between 'listening channel' block and 'Compute interferences' cornered and not bent like in the above handmade drawing.`  Also --  `I would like to add more space to the first column width to write 'LBT', 'FSA' and 'PHY', and make room to write the words 'Reader' and 'Tag' at both sides of the vertical line like in the following drawing:`

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Thank you. My code had many flaws. I was trying to understand yours. Why some rows have the `[a=-4]` that seems to add the extra space to the first column and not others. Also, may I ask you to comment on the change of the `block` style that now has `#1` and the line `block/.default=0,`.  I do not see why the use of `|[block]|` and what is doing.

Comment: I add some explanation. @user1993416

Comment: +1, I really like your programming style, it's simple and readable. Bravo !